# Is there a more efficient way to group this by array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm inside a while loop gathering the title and the accompanying array with groups from the database.

My data looks like this (please note that I need more fields but for the sake of simplicity I only show two):

```
**Title**               |   **Groups**
Random Title One    |   array(Group A)
Another Title       |   array(Group A, Group B, Group C, Group D, Group E)
```

I'm running through each line with a while loop. Now I would like to show this by Group. Like this:

```
Group A:    Random Title One, Another Title
Group B:    Another Title
Group C:    Another Title
Group D:    Another Title
Group E:    Another Title
```

The best way that I see to handle this is with a foreach loop inside my while loop going through the Groups.
That would look like this:

```
<?php

    foreach ($arrayGroups as $group) {
        switch ($group) {
            case "Group A":
                $arrGroupA[]['title'] = $title;
                break;
            case "Group B":
                $arrGroupB[]['title'] = $title;
                break;
            case "Group C":
                $arrGroupC[]['title'] = $title;
                break;
            case "Group D":
                $arrGroupD[]['title'] = $title;
                break;
            case "Group E":
                $arrGroupE[]['title'] = $title;
                break;
        }
    }
?>
```

However, even though I know that there are no more than five groups, I don't like this way and doubt whether this is the best way to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try putting them in a single array, for example:

```
foreach ($arrayGroups as $group) {
       $groups[$group][] = array( 
            'title' => $title, 
       );
}
```

That way you can access them with `$groups[groupName][some index]['title']`

Not sure if it's faster performance wise, though, but It allows you to input a variable amount of groups automatically.

Comment: Thank you, I like your way better then mine! Especially since it doesn't has the group names hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your result is always going to be in order, lets say

```
array(Group A, Group B, Group C, Group D, Group E)
```

or

```
array(Group A, Group D, Group E)
```

etc.

You could perhaps make it more efficient by not performing all of the comparisons each time.  In other words don't do the 'Group A' comparison if you're on the second group in the record's array, as 'Group A' would always appear first.  You still want to "short circuit" out when there is a match like your 'break' is doing in the switch.

here is some java-like pseudo code sorry I am not a php guy:

```
//traverse all groups for the current record
for (int i=0; i<currentRecordGroups.length; i++) {

  // traverse the possible groups, starting with the index of the 
  // current group from the current record (allGroups must also be sorted)
  for(int j = i; j<allGroups.length; j++) {

    if(currentRecordGroups[i] == allGroups[j]) {
      // add the title to the collection for group allGroups[j] here...
      break; //break for j
    }
  }
}
```